# Chartjs: How can I group datasets closer if I have maxBarThickness set?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart where I've set a `maxBarThickness` on my axis. When the chart is populated with a lot of data, the datasets are close together, but when there are just a few data points, the datasets look wide apart. [image: exemplified in this image]

I have tried setting `categoryPercentage` to a smaller percentage but when the chart is populated with a lot of data (or on page resize), the chart looks wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3922) you cannot change the space between bars if you decide to set a `barThickness` (I assume it does not work when `maxBarThickness` is set either but I might be wrong, if so I'll delete this answer)

According to the previous link, you have two solutions:

- If you want to keep your bar thickness (answer to the github issue):

> If you don't want to stretch out the bar to fill the extra space, you have to reduce the width of the canvas.

- Otherwise you could set a `barPercentage` and a `categoryPercentage` on your chart, without a `barThickness` or a `maxBarThickness`:

  ```
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      categoryPercentage: 0.8,
      barPercentage: 0.9
    }]
  },
  ```

Those are the default values.

---

Related questions :

[Chart.js Bar Chart: How to remove space between the bars in v2.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879445/chart-js-bar-chart-how-to-remove-space-between-the-bars-in-v2-3)

[CharJS 2.5.0 - How to remove space between bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42300130/charjs-2-5-0-how-to-remove-space-between-bars)

[Reduce space between ticks in horizontal bar-chart chartJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43105471/reduce-space-between-ticks-in-horizontal-bar-chart-chartjs)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but not setting the `maxBarThickness` will stretch the bars and I'd like it to not be thicker than in this image. Also setting the `categoryPercentage` to make it account for 2 bars of 30 thickness each, while it will look good in this example, it won't look good if there are 20+ entries, not just 3 as you see here

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to bring the .5 bars closer together from the 2nd entry here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#barpercentage-vs-categorypercentage

Comment: Have you tried to set your canvas' width according to your number of bars ? Or do you want it to be of a fixed width no matter how many bars it displays ?

Comment: Fixed width unfortunately.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot find a solution that satisfies your needs, I'll edit my answer to add related questions and wait to see if someone can help you